# Cannot publish from SBT

Tags: sbt, nexus

I am trying unsuccessfully to publish from SBT into a Nexus repository running on my network.  Attempts to publish fail with a forbidden error

[image]

If I look at the Nexus side of things with trace debugging on, I can see the request, but there is no Authorization header in the request.

[image]

This is my build.sbt

[image]

And this is my credentials file

[image]

I have used curl to see what the Realm should be, which hopefully I have reflected in my credentials file

[image]

But nothing I do seems to get the Authorization header in the PUT request.  Is there something obvious I am missing?  I feel like I am spinning my wheels.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

This did end up being how I had set up my files.  My build.sbt file was fine.  However, in my credentials, my Host value contains a port, which was confusing the IvyAuthenticator.  I ended up seeing this error message when running through sbt shell in IntelliJ

[image]

My issue was that, in my credentials file, my host ended with the ":8081" value, and it looks like IvyAuthenticator was using the host name without the port information.

So, after updating my credentials file, so that the host value was just the machine name without any port details, my publish succeeded.